# javascript stops working when switching from text field to select

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, forms, dom

I'm trying to do javascript, but I'm a ruby guy and really suck with javascript.  I have a one field form (text field and submit button) in which javascript only allows the form to be submitted if there is text in the field.  However, I switched the field type from a text field to a select.  Now, the form can't submit.  I am almost certain the problem is with my javascript.  Here is the code I have that word with a text field.  How do I get it to work with the select?

Form:

```
<form id="new_skill" class="new_skill" method="post" action="/skills" >
    <li>
        <input id="resume-field" class="field field288" type="text"
          value="Type a speciality you want to add to your profile" 
          title="Type a speciality you want to add to your profile" 
          name="skill[label]"></input>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input class="button button-add button-add-disabled" 
         type="submit" value="ADD +" name="commit"></input>
    </li>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
(function($){
    $(document).on('focusin', '#resume-field', function() {
        $(this).parents().find('.button-add-disabled').removeClass('button-add-disabled');
    }).on('focusout', '#resume-field', function(){
        if(this.value==' '||this.title==this.value) {
            $(this).parents().find('.button-add').addClass('button-add-disabled');
        } else {
            $(this).parents().find('.button-add').removeClass('button-add-disabled');
        }

    });     

    $('.button-add-disabled').click(function(){
        return !$(this).hasClass('button-add-disabled');
    });
}(jQuery));
```

css:

```
.button-add { width: 49px; height: 28px; border: solid 1px #8c8c8c; display: block; 
   font-size: 11px; line-height: 28px ; color: #fff; text-align: center; 
   font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif; transition: none; margin: 0 0 0 auto; 
   border-radius: 3px; }
.button-add:hover { text-decoration: none;
   -webkit-transition:none; 
      -moz-transition:none; 
       -ms-transition:none; 
        -o-transition:none; 
           transition:none; 
}
.button-add-disabled { background: url(/assets/add-specialities-disabled.png) 
   repeat-x 0 0; box-shadow: 0 0 0 0; margin-left:35px;  }
.button-add-disabled:hover { background: url(/assets/add-specialities-disabled.png) 
   repeat-x 0 0; box-shadow: 0 0 0 0;  }
```

Html for form with drop down:

```
<select id="resume-field" name="skill[label]">
    <option value="1" title="option_1"></option>
    <option value="2" title="option 2" selected="selected"></option>
</select>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery click function not being called](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21053295/jquery-click-function-not-being-called)

Comment: It is not a duplicate.  I am ahead of him as i got it to work with a text field.

Comment: Can you post the HTML for the SELECT please?  If you are turning the text field into a SELECT, there may be many reasons why it's not working (e.g., not OPTION elements, mismatched IDs, etc.)

Comment: @Philip7899 if not a duplicate, then it is at least a good example of [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). :) A JSFiddle would be nice, too!

Comment: I replaced input with select, try this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nMeYn/

Comment: Josh, I am uploading my html now.

Comment: Surendran, I tried your jsfiddle and it submits always.  What I am trying to do is have it so if the user hasn't selected anything yet, it cannot be submitted.  If the user has, than it can be submitted.

Comment: try this... maybe it helps to put you onto the right track... http://jsfiddle.net/nMeYn/1/

Comment: Vickel, thanks, I tried yours but yours will submit always.  I only want it to submit if the user has selected something.

Comment: check this: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-get-the-text-value-of-a-selected-option/

Comment: @ Philip7899 I've updated the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nMeYn/2/

Comment: Have you tried my answer? http://jsfiddle.net/uBzqW/

Comment: BTW, since you want the button to become available immediately upon change, and not just when user leaves the control, the better method to use is `.change()`. Hmmph. Just realized Andre mentioned that fact already...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a minimal example ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andrelaszlo/2NCXs/2/)), doing what I think you asked for, but not using your code. You can probably adapt it if it does what you want.

**HTML**

```
<form>
    <select id="selectme">
        <option value="">-- Please select one --</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
        <option value="3">III</option>
    </select> 
    <input type="submit" value="submit" id="clickme">
</form>
```

**JS**

```
$(function(){
    $("#clickme").prop("disabled", true);
    $("#selectme").change(function(){
        if ($("#selectme").val() != "") {
            $("#clickme").removeAttr("disabled");
        } else {
            $("#clickme").prop("disabled", true);
        }
    });
})
```

**CSS**

```
#clickme {
    background-color: #f00;
}

#clickme:disabled {
    background-color: #eee;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer almost helps perfectly.  As far as how it submits, its perfect.  The only problem is that the styles/colors associated with button-add and button-add-disabled now don't happen.

Comment: What i mean is, the color should change when the link is clickable and when it goes back to being not clickable.

Comment: Now the colors are changing as well. Changed the behavior of the select box a bit, since it was impossible to select the "empty" value once you selected a real value, in the previous version.

Answer (score 0):

you stated that you have switched the input field type from text to select. Therefore you need to add this kind of html:

```
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I'm a bit ashamed to admit that I recognize this code, and that it's copied from w3schools. :)

Comment: Yeah, I'm just joking. There are a lot of [w3schools haters](http://www.w3fools.com/) out there. Ten years ago there were not many other good references for beginners, so I learnt a lot from them (and forgot most of it, it seems).

Answer (score 0):

To start, your HTML is a little bit off:

```
<form id="new_skill" class="new_skill" method="post" action="/skills" >
    <!-- needs a parent UL element -->
    <li>
        <input id="resume-field" class="field field288" type="text"
          value="Type a speciality you want to add to your profile" 
          title="Type a speciality you want to add to your profile" 
          name="skill[label]"></input>
          <!-- as a side not, input tags can be self-close (<input type="text" />)
    </li>
    <li>
        <input class="button button-add button-add-disabled" 
         type="submit" value="ADD +" name="commit"></input>
    </li>
</form>
```

If you've changed your *input* to a *select* element, then you need *option* elements, of which each can have a "value" attribute, as follows:

```
<select>
    <option value="something">Something</option>
</select>
```

In the context of what you are trying to do, I'm not sure that a *select* element would fit your needs if you are wanting the user to type something in...  You could pre-fill the *select* element with *option* elements, each corresponding to a specific "specialty that they want to add to their profile".

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED and SIMPLIFIED:

Assuming that you did change the `<input>` elements to `<select><option></select>` elements, your code will work fine with only minor changes.

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/uBzqW/2/)</kbd>

Really, you only need to track the **change** event:

**HTML:**

```
<form id="new_skill" class="new_skill" method="post" action="/skills" >
    <li>
        Select a specialty to add to your profile:<br>
        <select id="resume-field" name="skill[label]">
            <option value="default">Select a speciality:</option>
            <option value="cod3r">Programming</option>
            <option value="pizza">Pizza consumption</option>
        </select>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input class="button button-add button-add-disabled" 
         type="submit" value="ADD +" name="commit"></input>
    </li>
</form>
```

**javascript/jQuery:**

```
$(document).on('change', '#resume-field', function() {
    if(this.value=='default') {
        $(this).parents().find('.button-add').addClass('button-add-disabled');
    } else {
        $(this).parents().find('.button-add').removeClass('button-add-disabled');
    }

});
```

PS: Of course, to make the jsFiddle work I also had to temporarily remove the `url()` etc from your css...